# Поменять стрелку в ExpandableList View

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Можно ли в `ExpandableListView` поменять в группе стрелочку выпадающего списка, что бы она отображалась не с левой стороны, а с правой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашла решение, что бы поменять позицию  `Expandable indicator` слева на право, использовала этот код:

```
 Display newDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = newDisplay.getWidth();
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            expListView.setIndicatorBounds(width-50, width);
        } else {
            expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width-50, width);
        }
```